# Are closing tags allowed for void elements in HTML5?

Tags: html

Are end tags allowed for void elements in HTML5? Were they allowed in prior versions of HTML, what is the reasoning. Coming from a XML background, void elements are allowed end tags so was not sure.

Comment: No. E.g. for the `br` element, these are allowed: `<br>` (preferred in HTML 5), `<br/>` and `<br />`. If you write `<br></br>` the opening tag is already interpreted as the full tag, while the `</br>` is just considered a syntax error.

Comment: Why does XML allow but HTML does not? @connexo

Comment: Because XML does not allow omitting closing a tag, which HTML does. I already explained that in my previous comment.

Comment: Not 100% a duplicate, the answers there provide an answer to this question as well.

Comment: HTML5 has an alternative, [XML compliant syntax](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html#the-xhtml-syntax), in which closing tags are allowed for void elements. You access it by serving the page with the `application/xhtml+xml` content type.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning behind start and end tags are to determine where an element starts and ends, so no they are not allowed since they have no content.

And this is from the spec page.

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.

[W3.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements)

Comment: Why link to a decade old and abandoned working draft?

Comment: @Alohci Reference link updated.